# How to keep showing the 'popover' on hovering on the anchorEl and 'popover' as well?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dom-events

Here in this example of `material-ui` https://material-ui.com/utils/popover/#mouse-over-interaction

Follow these steps for the example  `material-ui` https://material-ui.com/utils/popover/#mouse-over-interaction

1. In the above example keep the mouse on the text `Hover with a Popover.`
   --- you see the `popover`
2. Try to move your mouse near the `popover` --- `popover` disappears right?
   But I wanna show the popover even if I hover on  `popover`

And make popover disappear only if the user is not hovering on either `popover` or the `Hover with a Popover.` (basically anchorEl)

I am copying code from their demo

```
  import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import Popover from '@material-ui/core/Popover';
    import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
    import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

    const styles = theme => ({
      popover: {
        pointerEvents: 'none',
      },
      paper: {
        padding: theme.spacing.unit,
      },
    });

    class MouseOverPopover extends React.Component {
      state = {
        anchorEl: null,
      };

      handlePopoverOpen = event => {
        this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
      };

      handlePopoverClose = () => {
        this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
      };

      render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { anchorEl } = this.state;
        const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

        return (
          <div>
            <Typography
              aria-owns={open ? 'mouse-over-popover' : undefined}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onMouseEnter={this.handlePopoverOpen}
              onMouseLeave={this.handlePopoverClose}
            >
              Hover with a Popover.
            </Typography>
            <Popover
              id="mouse-over-popover"
              className={classes.popover}
              classes={{
                paper: classes.paper,
              }}
              open={open}
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              onClose={this.handlePopoverClose}
              disableRestoreFocus
            >
              <Typography>I use Popover.</Typography>
            </Popover>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    MouseOverPopover.propTypes = {
      classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    export default withStyles(styles)(MouseOverPopover);
```

What code change I need to make here? 
You may experiment https://codesandbox.io/s/6l3wk6kv3

Comment: what you want is not clear for me ?? can you explain a bit differently what you want exactly ?

Comment: Updated. Can you check now?

Comment: I believe the issue is not gaining focus. If you use `onClick` as the trigger, you'll find you can't actually click the Popover at all.

Answer (score 46):

I had the same problem, didn't find any answer and I took a while to understand how to fix it.

Actually the problem comes from the pointerEvents: none that you need on the popover to prevent your onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave to be triggered at the same time.

But you can set for the content of your popover pointerEvents: auto.

Then you can add a onMouseEnter and a onMouseLeave on the content of your popover.

Here is an exemple to make it more explicit :

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Popover } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  popover: {
    pointerEvents: 'none',
  },
  popoverContent: {
    pointerEvents: 'auto',
  },
}));

const MyComponent = ({ loading, login, wrong, clearWrongLogin }: Props) => {
  const [openedPopover, setOpenedPopover] = useState(false)
  const popoverAnchor = useRef(null);

  const popoverEnter = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    setOpenedPopover(true)
  };

  const popoverLeave = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    setOpenedPopover(false)
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

return (
    <div>
         <span
          ref={popoverAnchor}
          aria-owns="mouse-over-popover"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onMouseEnter={popoverEnter}
          onMouseLeave={popoverLeave}
        >Hover this el !
        </span>
        <Popover
        id="mouse-over-popover"
        className={classes.popover}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.popoverContent,
        }}
        open={openedPopover}
        anchorEl={popoverAnchor.current}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'right',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        PaperProps={{onMouseEnter: popoverEnter, onMouseLeave: popoverLeave}}
      >
        <div>
          My popover content...
        </div>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-79he1 for the working example.

Comment: Life saver. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 6):

In **MUI v5** :

I searched for the solution a lot, and the easiest way is using `"material-ui-popup-state"`. Be sure because it was introduced by MUI [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popover/);

I made a complete example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-thunder-6h9lfx)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import PopupState, { bindTrigger, bindPopover ,bindHover } from 'material-ui-popup-state';
import HoverPopover from "material-ui-popup-state/HoverPopover";

export default function PopoverPopupState() {
    return (
        <PopupState variant="popover" popupId="demo-popup-popover">
            {(popupState) => (
                <div>
                    <Button variant="contained" {...bindHover(popupState)}>
                        Open Popover
                    </Button>
                    <HoverPopover
                        {...bindPopover(popupState)}
                        anchorOrigin={{
                            vertical: 'bottom',
                            horizontal: 'center',
                        }}
                        transformOrigin={{
                            vertical: 'top',
                            horizontal: 'center',
                        }}
                    >
                        <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
                    </HoverPopover>
                </div>
            )}
        </PopupState>
    );
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This really helped me figure this out.

Comment: Thanks! Also works with v4 by using the version 1.9.3 as pointed [here](https://github.com/jcoreio/material-ui-popup-state#requirements)

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  popover: {
    pointerEvents: "none"
  },
  paper: {
    pointerEvents: "auto",
    padding: theme.spacing(1)
  }
}));

export default function MouseOverPopover() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handlePopoverOpen = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handlePopoverClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={handlePopoverOpen} onMouseLeave={handlePopoverClose}>
      <Typography
        aria-owns={open ? "mouse-over-popover" : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
      >
        Hover with a Popover.
      </Typography>
      <Popover
        id="mouse-over-popover"
        className={classes.popover}
        classes={{
          paper: classes.paper
        }}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        onClose={handlePopoverClose}
        disableRestoreFocus
      >
        <Typography>I use Popover.</Typography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is just a better formatted copy of the answer. Please suggest an edit instead.

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

##### MUI v5

---

```js
<Menu
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    open={open}
    onClose={handleMouseLeave}
    sx={{
        pointerEvents: 'none'
    }}
    MenuListProps={{
        'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button'
    }}
    PaperProps={{
        onMouseEnter: handleMouseEnter,
        onMouseLeave: handleMouseLeave,
        sx: {
            pointerEvents: 'auto'
        }
    }}
>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMouseLeave}>Profile</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMouseLeave}>My account</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onClick={handleMouseLeave}>Logout</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calling rowHover method :
    rowHover= (event) => {
        const rowId = event.currentTarget?.dataset?.id;
        console.log(rowId);
        this.state.popRowData = rowId;
        this.setState({ popRowData: rowId });
        this.state.anchorE1 = true;
        this.state.open = true;
      };
    
On Mouse event
                          onMouseEnter: this.rowHover, // <------- Here
                          onMouseLeave: this.handlePopoverClose
    Popover called : 
        <Popover
                id="mouse-over-popover"
                sx={{
                  pointerEvents: 'none',
                }}
                open={this.state.open}
                anchorEl={this.state.anchorE1}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'bottom',
                  horizontal: 'center',
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'center',
                  horizontal: 'center',
                }}
                onClose={this.handlePopoverClose}
                disableRestoreFocus
              >
                <Typography sx={{ p: 1 }}>{this.state.popRowData}</Typography>
              </Popover>
```

Answer (score -1):

MUI v5

```
export const MouseOverPopover = () => {
  const [openedPopover, setOpenedPopover] = useState(false);
  const popoverAnchor = useRef(null);

  const popoverEnter = () => {
    setOpenedPopover(true);
  };

  const popoverLeave = () => {
    setOpenedPopover(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onMouseEnter={popoverEnter}
        onMouseLeave={popoverLeave}
        ref={popoverAnchor}
      />

      <Popover
        open={openedPopover}
        anchorEl={popoverAnchor.current}
        sx={{
          pointerEvents: "none",
        }}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left",
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left",
        }}
        PaperProps={{ onMouseEnter: popoverEnter, onMouseLeave: popoverLeave }}
      >
        <Box sx={{ pointerEvents: "auto" }}>{content}</Box>
      </Popover>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61486098/10488304). Be careful of using `pointerEvents: 'none'` and `pointerEvents: 'auto'` to works truly.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: that is not an answer

Answer (score -7):

[codesandbox DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/3yzp9px0q1)

I hacked my way through it by adding a `setTimeout()` function for the `onMouseLeave` event...I am sure that there is other ways of doing it, but it depends on your specific needs

```js
  handlePopoverClose = () => {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
    }, 3000);
  };
```

Comment: Since React can unmount the component in the middle of the interaction this may not be the best approach. The least would be adding a clearTimeout on unmount, but also not an optimal approach.